# Cannot run arquillian tests in wildfly

Tags: eclipse, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I am having problems running tests with arquillian/wildfly 10.0.0.Final.

The error is a LifecycleException: Could not start container, due to TimeoutException: Managed Server was not started within [120] s (I have upped the timeout from 60 to see if it would make a difference).

Funny thing is, Wildfly starts fine (within the default 60s) and then sits there
until it's told to shut down, which it does.
I had tests in another project which used to run but now don't run anymore, they fail with the same error (although they do still run on Jenkins).

Also, turning on Shrinkwrap.writeTo(System.out, Formatters.VERBOSE) (used to build the war file) does not produce any output (which I also know it did in the past)

What has changed:

The server was hooked up to LDAP to managed admin logins, and a datasource was added
Eclipse was updated to Neon 3

Arquillian configuration file is:

```
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
  <container qualifier="wildfly" default="true">
    <configuration>
      <property name="jbossHome">/Users/turekg/dev/apps/wildfly-10.0.0.Final</property>
      <property name="startupTimeoutInSeconds">120</property>
    </configuration>
  </container>
```

I am using ant with Ivy to manage test dependencies and these are:

```
  <dependency org="org.jboss.arquillian" name="arquillian-bom" rev="1.1.11.Final" conf="test->default"/>
   <dependency org="org.jboss.arquillian.junit" name="arquillian-junit-container" rev="1.1.11.Final" conf="test->default"/>
   <dependency org="org.wildfly.arquillian" name="wildfly-arquillian-container-managed" rev="2.0.0.Final" conf="test->default"/>
   <dependency org="org.wildfly.security" name="wildfly-security-manager" rev="1.1.2.Final" conf="test->default"/>
   <dependency org="org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver" name="shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain" rev="2.2.4" conf="test->default"/>
   <dependency org="org.jboss.arquillian.extension" name="arquillian-rest-client-impl-3x" rev="1.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT" conf="test->default"/>
```

Thanx
Gaby

Comment: OK, so it must be something about the changes I made to Wildfly. I've downloaded Wildfly 10.1.0.Final and the old tests are running again. Could it be the added security? If so, shouldn't I be able to pass on the login info?

Comment: I noticed I had not updated the management login information for wildfly in Eclipse (ie it was still the default admin/admin). Once I did that, I could see the actual war file being deployed (it was not even getting that far) but I am still getting the timeout error